# building a function to add checks to amazon deequ framework

Tags: scala, apache-spark, methods, amazon-deequ

Using amazon deequ library I'm trying to build a function that takes 3 parameters, the check object, a string telling what constraint needs to be run and another string that provides the constraint criteria. I have a bunch of checks that I want to read from a mysql table. My intention is to iterate through all the checks that I get from the mysql table and build a check object using the function I described above and run the checks on a source dataframe
Here a example of the amazon deequ 
https://towardsdatascience.com/automated-data-quality-testing-at-scale-using-apache-spark-93bb1e2c5cd0

So the function call looks something like this,

`var _check = build_check_object_function(check_object, "hasSize", "10000")`

This function should add a new hasSize check to the check_object and return that.

The part where I'm stuck is how to translate the hasSize string to the hasSize function.

```
    var _check = Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Data Validation Check")
    val listOfFunctions= _check.getClass.getMethods.filter(!_.getName().contains('$'))
    for (function <- listOfFunctions) {
       if( function.getName().toLowerCase().contains(row(2).asInstanceOf[String].toLowerCase())) {
         _check = _check.function(row(3))
        }else{
            println("Not a match")}
        }
```

Here is the error that I'm getting

```
<console>:38: error: value function is not a member of com.amazon.deequ.checks.Check
   if( function.getName().toLowerCase().contains(row(2).asInstanceOf[String].toLowerCase())) {_check = _check.function(row(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use runtime reflection or build a thin translation layer between your database and the deequ declarations.

I would suggest you go with translating database constraint/check strings explicitly to deequ declarations, e.g.:

```scala
if (constraint == "hasSize") {
  // as Constraint
  Constraint.sizeConstraint(_ <= 10)
  // as Check
  Check(CheckLevel.Error, "name").hasSize(_ <= 10)
}
```

Comment: yeah...but this way...if there's a new rule in deequ library ....I have to come back to my code and add that in to my code

Comment: The other option is to store the actual `deequ` sourcecode in the table and use the Scala compiler to compile it. See this answer for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453541/load-constraints-from-csv-file-amazon-deequ/69804027#69804027